# How to play a list of tracks with NAudio in C#

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to do a project for school, including both c# and databases. It basically is an Audio Player that takes the tracks from paths in a SQL Server 
database locally.

My question is, since I can't solve my problem myself, how can I play a list of songs?

I am using a `WaveOutEvent` object called `outputDevice` and an `AudioFileReader`.

I tried getting the index of the list and playing it and it "works", or better, the debugging says that the `PlaybackState` of the `outputDevice` is 'Playing' but it doesn't actually play the music.

Here's some code:

The working part of it:

```
if (songsQueue.Count != 0)
{
    //where nQueue is the position of the list
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)songsQueue[nQueue];

    if (outputDevice == null)
    {
        outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
        outputDevice.PlaybackStopped += OnPlaybackStopped;
    }

    if (audioReader == null)
    {
        string path = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        audioReader = new AudioFileReader(Application.StartupPath + @path);
        outputDevice.Init(audioReader);
        lblArtist.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        lblTrack.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        outputDevice.Play();
    }
}
```

The part that is not working:

```
audioReader.Dispose();
outputDevice.Dispose();
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)songsQueue[nQueue + 1];
string path = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
audioReader = new AudioFileReader(Application.StartupPath + @path);

outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
outputDevice.Init(audioReader);

lblArtist.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
lblTrack.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

outputDevice.Play();
```

I'd expect it to play, since the labels `lblArtist` and `lblTrack` change and the `outputDevice` says that it's playing.

Thank you all for the help in advance! :D